# Do I have to constantly change the default python version?

Tags: python, linux

I had to change the default python to python2.7. Now I'm always running into problems because there are a bunch of apps that need python2.x as default and others that need python3.x and so I'm constantly changing the default to accommodate that.

Did I broke something, and is there a way to solve the constant changing of the default python version?

Comment: On which system? Which scripts, which libraries?

Comment: Yes, it's called virtual environment.

Comment: Why did you change the default in the first place, for what application? Applications usually use the appropriate version without any user interaction.

Comment: I was asking because most applications I have installed use python3 but Dropbox needed python2. I just changed the #!/usr/bin/python on the /usr/bin/dropbox script to #!/usr/bin/python2.7 (should have remembered that earlier), and it's fine now, just in case someone stumbles upon a similar situation

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to solve the constant changing of the default python version?

The usual solution is [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Virtualenv manage dependencies, it won't make an old python2.7 library work with python 3.

Comment: Nobody claimed it would.